# how to play .swf files in windows store app

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps, flash, winrt-xaml

Currently I am working on windows store app, and there is a need to play `.swf` file in that app.

I have developed the same app in **WPF** with .swf file, but in windows store app I couldn't, help me to find the solution. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

[Simply, it's not possible right now to embed/play flash files.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx#AN3)

Comment: what about .FLV files or FLA file in windows store app

Comment: FLV or FLA is not supported, [you need to write your own decoder for that.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/5b03c60c-f0a3-4c26-97e2-37f6bc654477/playing-flv-in-mediaelement-control-in-metro?forum=winappswithcsharp) also check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0b1d2d0d-f7ba-4a9e-80bb-d67059453c33/play-mpegflv-files-im-media-element?forum=winappswithcsharp)

Answer (score 0):

There is two method to do this.
1- by shockwave player component
2- by webBrowser

[See this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/how-to-play-flash-in-windows-forms-application-using-C-Sharp/)